# How to open new Terminal tab and get focus back to the prev tab?

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, osascript

I want to run a command in a terminal tab which will open a new tab, run a command there too and then get the focus back to the previous Terminal tab (the one i run the first command), is it possible?
using of corse osascript.

what i have so far:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'do script "cd /path/to/dir; clear;" in selected tab of the front window' -e 'end tell' > /dev/null
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to key code "48" using control down' > /dev/null
```

this will only work if i have only 2 opened tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set selected of tab 1 of front window to true'`

Replace the `1` with the appropriate tab number to select whichever tab you like.

Or you can save the current tab number:

```
osascript \
    -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set oldTab to the selected tab of the front window' \
    -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' \
    -e 'delay 1' \
    -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set selected of oldTab to true'
```

Comment: like I said it works if i have 2 tabs opened and i run the command from the 1st tab. if you know how to do it dynamically, it would be even better!

Comment: Works on my machine with three tabs open.

Comment: right, but what i meant is that it will go for the first tab (if you ran the command on the second one). what i wanted is that if you run the command on the second tab (out of 3 for example) it will go back to the second instead of to the first.

Comment: So just save the old selected tab first: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set oldTab to the selected tab of the front window' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down' -e 'delay 1' -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set selected of oldTab to true'`